# Javascript - How i do compare two objects of an array?

Tags: javascript, object

I have some objects into an array. I want to compare object[0].position with object[1].position and If These two values were equal, object[0].position = 0. how can I do this?

`

```
function carInfo(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.position = 0;
}

let numOfCars = +prompt("Enter Number of Cars: ");
for (let i = 0; i < numOfCars; i++) {
  carNames.push(new carInfo(prompt(`Enter Name of Car No.${i + 1} : `)));
}

let str = "*";
str += str.repeat(300);
console.log(str);

function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    array[i].position += temp;
    if (array[i].position >= 300) {
      alert("game end! " + '"' + array[i].name + '"' + " win");
      break;
    }
    
  }
  return array;
}
```

`

Comment: Can more than 2 objects share the same `position` and should they all be set to `position: 0`? Do the object comparisons only occur between 2 consecutively indexed objects? I think you need to clarify your question.

Comment: [link] (https://codepen.io/msna218/pen/VwKQvZJ)

Comment: no. i need to if object[index].position === object[index+1].position in that case object[index].position = 0. no i don't need to be all set 0

Answer (score 0):

by position of them. I want say:

```
If(object[i].position === object[i+1].position){
 object[i].position = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of your objects in the array have a 'position' attribute, you can map over the array and for each item check their position. For each object in the array, are you trying to compare it to the next object in the array? If so, it might look something like this:

```
objectArr.map((object, index) => {
   if (object.position === objectArr[index + 1].position){
       // The position's are equal, do something
   }
})
```

If for every object in the array you'd like to compare it to ALL the other objects in the array, you may want to sort the array first based on the objects position's to save time.

Comment: I do this and give an error " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined"

Comment: function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    array[i].position += temp;
    if (array[i].position >= 300) {
      alert("game end! " + '"' + array[i].name + '"' + " win");
      break;
    }
    array.map((object, index) => {
      if (object.position === object[index + 1].position) {
        object.position = 0;
      }
    });
  }
  return array;
}

Comment: Then my guess is you are not properly setting the position of each object. Can I see the code where you create the array and set the positions?

Comment: Take a look at the changes I've made. Notice that at the end of the file I added `start()` to call the start function. https://codepen.io/gavischneider/pen/poEajbp?editors=1011

Comment: No problem. If my answer helped you, please mark it as the correct answer so other people can see it.

Answer (score 0):

I do this to my code

```
    objectArr.map((object, index) => {
   if (object.position === objectArr[index + 1].position){
       // The position's are equal, do something
   }
})
```

but give me error

```
Cannot read property 'position' of undefined
```

i do this

```
    function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    array[i].position += temp;
    if (array[i].position >= 300) {
      alert("game end! " + '"' + array[i].name + '"' + " win");
      break;
    }
    array.map((object, index) => {
      if (object.position === object[index + 1].position) {
        object.position = 0;
      }
    });
  }
  return array;
}
```